# For what reasons i should call UrlConnection.connect()

Tags: android, url, httpurlconnection

I'm confused a litle bit about `URLConnection.connect()` and `URL.openConnection()`, from official Java docs it says that `URL.openConnection()` returns only `URLConnection` instance but not already opened connection so I must call `URLConnection.connect()` somewhere further in code, but in Android tutorials http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html `URLConnection.connect()` wasn't called. So is a `URLConnection.getInputStream` establishes a connection too? And when I should call connect() method?

Comment: http://queue.acm.org/blogposting.cfm?id=38893 is interesting and yes, opening streams opens a connection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK it's useless to call `connect()`. Maybe by calling this the state of the HUC changes from CREATED to CONNECTED. But in all docs I've read it is sayed that it doesn't hurt to call `connect()` and it's ignored if you're already connected.

So in fact, when you call a method like `getInputStream()`, `getContentLength()`, `getOutputStream()`, the connection will be established to the server if it is not already done.

But one thing is often used wrong IMO: in many code samples you can see that `getInputStream()` is called before `getResponseCode()`. I've observed that `getInputStream()` throws an Exception when you call it in case of HTTP status code >= 400.

So I recommend doing it this way (pseudo-code):

```
if (method == POST || method == PUT)
    con.setDoOutput(true)
    writeBody(con)

statusCode = con.getResponseCode()

if (statusCode is successful)
    readStream(con.getInputStream())
else
    // if you expect some information in the body in case of error...
    readStream(con.getErrorStream())
```

You can read the whole (more involved) code [here](https://github.com/hgoebl/DavidWebb/blob/master/src/main/java/com/goebl/david/Webb.java#L356-L389).